# Filestream does not free file for other processes

Tags: c#

I have the following code to write a file. The problem is that if I want to overwrite the same file, it is "locked". The file is opened by another process.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\New\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    str.Write(jsonFile);
    str.Dispose();
    str.Close();
}
```

I send a json string to an API, which then generates the file. So I guess it might be a problem in IIS.

EDIT:
By research I have still tried the following code, but which leads to the same result

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\New\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.Write(jsonFile);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

EDIT 2:
After reading the comments, it probably has nothing to do with the Filestream to itself. Here is more information about my application:
I have a WPF application which sends a post to my API through a ButtonClick. This is triggered as follows:

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Seal();
    }
```

The Seal method says the following:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Seal()
    {
        var result = await RequestManager.DoPost<bool>("FOO", foo);
    }
```

The RequestManager says the following:

```
public static async Task<R> DoPost<R>(String route, Object payload, String contenttype)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        route = route.StartsWith("/") ? route : "/" + route;

        var content = new StringContent(serializer.Serialize(payload), Encoding.UTF8, contenttype);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(RequestManager.API_URL + route, content);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return (R)serializer.Deserialize(result, typeof(R));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ResponseException(response.StatusCode, response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }
```

I really do not know where my error is, or where the request must be closed.

Comment: The `Dispose` and `Close` calls are redundant with a `using`-statement

Comment: Need more information, this could be being locked by you or any other process. Please provide re-creation steps. For example what exactly is calling this? Is this a multi-user, multi-threaded or web environment? Obviously a file cannot be written to by multiple process at exactly the same time.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1888/

Comment: Disposing the stream *does* close the file.  There is no problem with FileStream or IIS. There are hundreds of thousand of IIS sites that write data to the disk without problems. Are you trying to write to the *same* file from multiple requests at the same time though?

Comment: Where does `fileName` come from? Are you sure the file doesn't already exist or that it isn't used by another request? What are you trying to do? If you try to save an uploaded file, why not use ASP.NET's own methods? They work

Comment: Are you trying to write to a temporary file? Use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a unique file. A log file? Use any of the logging libraries that know how to handle concurrent writing to a log file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `fileName` stands in the json string. The error only appears if I want to overwrite an existing file. The file exists and I would like to update it if necessary.

Comment: @Hadda yes, and as I said, if two requests try to handle the same file, you'll get an error. You'll also get an error if you have the file open in Notepad, or if another application opened the file without the FileShare.Delete permission. FileStream isn't broken. Find who's locked the file first, instead of guessing. You can do that with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or the [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) utility

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there a way to end/close the request. I thought that the `using` would end the request

Comment: It does. What does the request have to do with the *filestream* ?

Answer (score -1):

This error could occur when multiple threads are attempting to write at the same file. Your code above works with a little modification

```
  private static object lk = new object();
     lock (lk)
        {
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\New\\" +fileName,FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
str.Write(jsonFile);
str.Dispose();
str.Close();
 }
  }
```

Comment: There is no point having two using statements there though. wrapping all in the first using statement works fine.

Comment: If there was a concurrency problem before, there are 2^N now - this lock blocks *all* file writes, whether they try to write to the same file or not. Who said that `FileStream` or `using` are broken anyway? They are used by millions of times per day, by thousands of web sites without requiring extra locking. When problems arise, it's the *code* that's at fault

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue with all your code samples but all passed except when i tried writing to the file in Parallel which i solved by adding the lock. If your are on development machine, you can try to delete the file manually and test again.

Comment: Adding a lock isn't a *solution*. At best it's a cover up. *Why* are two different threads trying to overwrite the same file? Lock or no lock, one of them is going to lose its data. Might as well hide the exception and continue. Overwriting is simply wrong in this case. Locking won't fix that. The worst case is that parallel processing becomes sequential, and the data is still lost.